# PHPExcel sheet index out of bounds exception

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to read an xlsx workbook, the following is the code I'm using so far just to set the active sheet

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './Classes/');

include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$xlWB = $reader->load('/' . $target_file);
$xlWB->setActiveSheetIndex(0); //EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
```

but I'm getting an exception:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'You tried to set a sheet active by the out of bounds index: 0. The actual number of sheets is 0.' in /[my root]/Classes/PHPExcel.php:695 Stack trace: #0 /[my-root]/conversion-demo.php(211): PHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0) #1 {main} thrown in **/[my root]/Classes/PHPExcel.php** on line **695**

The file is an .xlsx file, it does exist (the path is correct) and there are 3 sheets in the file.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: Can't you select the by name rather than Index. Can you try that?

Comment: If there isn't a sheet with index 0, then either the spreadsheet doesn't contain any worksheets, or there has been a problem loading the file..... whatever the case, only you have access to the file that it's failing with, so it's almost impossible for us to say anything more

Comment: @MarkBaker It was an issue loading the file, when opening on client machine it required a corrupt load. Thanks for the pointer thought I was going mad!!!

Comment: @MarkBaker Just tried with another xlsx workbook and getting the same results, perhaps it wasn't the workbook after all...

Comment: Nothing fundamentally wrong at all; I haven't a clue why it isn't working when it should work

Comment: @MarkBaker It's the 0 index thing that's nagging me - if there was no book available wouldn't the index be -1 ?

Comment: No, my only thoughts is that its another file (they seem to be cropping up more and more frequently these days) that's using non-standard namespacing for the worksheets, a file that was generated by some third-party application, and not by MS Excel itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107023/discussion-between-macro-man-and-mark-baker).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone get this error when using `$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetName$);` to get only a specific sheet of the workbook, double check the sheet name 'cause the it is case-sensitive.

Comment: The names didn't match

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on where you're getting the file from - I just had this problem on a file upload and changing the permissions in Windows\Temp fixed it.

Comment: The file is in a subfolder of my root directory on my server and has full read/write access.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload file manually.

Had the same issue right now. Excel template was commited in git repository, and git changed sheet somehow. So, I *uploaded local version to server* - now it works.

**Better way**: this may be resolved with `.gitattributes` file, just write this `*.xls binary` there, rename file and recommit